# Submit modal form with verification using laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, validation

I'm new to `laravel` and I don't know how to handle `laravel`, `ajax` and `jquery`
now I am in the process of inserting the data into the database, I managed to do it except that I have a problem at the level of the data validation is I wanted to `check the data at some point of entry and not after when I click on the submit button`.

So I'm using the following code :

My blade page :

```
<x-app-layout>
   <div class="container-fluid">   
   <div class="row">

       <div class="col-12">

            <h1>Castings</h1>

                 <div class="top-right-button-container">
                    
                     <div class="btn-group">
                         
                           <button type="button" name="create_record" id="create_record" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Create Record</button>
    
                     </div>

                    </div>
                
                     <div class="separator"></div>
       </div>

   </div>

    </div>


   <!-------------- Model Ajouter -------------------------------------->


  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="formModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                
                   <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <span id="form_result"></span>

      <form id="sample_form" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
        
       
                     {{ csrf_field() }}
                  <!--   <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id" /> -->
                        <div class="form-row">
                           
                              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                  <label for="casting_name">Nom</label>
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_name" name="casting_name" placeholder="Nom" >
                                   <!--  <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_name') }}</span> -->
                               </div>
                               <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                   <label for="casting_cin">CIN</label>
                                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_cin" name="casting_cin" placeholder="Cin">
                                <!--    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_cin') }}</span> -->
                                </div>
                                   
                                </div>
                                 <div class="form-row">
                                   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="casting_email">Email</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_email" name="casting_email"  placeholder="Email">
                               <!--            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_email') }}</span> -->
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="casting_phone">Téléphone</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_phone" name="casting_phone" placeholder="Téléphone">
                                          <!-- <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_phone') }}</span> -->
                                    </div>
                                   
                                  </div>
                                 <div class="form-row">

                                  <div class="form-group col-md-6">

                                        <label for="casting_age">Age</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="casting_age" name="casting_age" placeholder="Age">
                                          <!-- <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_age') }}</span> -->
                                    </div>
                                   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    
                                        <label for="casting_sexe">Sexe</label>

                                         <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

                      <input type="radio"  name="casting_sexe"  id="casting_sexeh" class="custom-control-input" value="homme">

                       
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="casting_sexeh">Homme</label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                      <input type="radio"  name="casting_sexe" id="casting_sexef" class="custom-control-input"  value="femme">
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="casting_sexef" >Femme</label>
                       
                    </div>
 
                                   </div>


                                    </div>        
                              
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <label for="casting_city">City</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="casting_city" id="casting_city">
                                          <!-- <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_city') }}</span> -->
                                    </div>
                                      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="casting_address">Address 2</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_address" name="casting_address" >
                                 <!--      <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_address') }}</span> -->
                                       
                                </div>
                                   </div>
                                
                                 <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                       <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="custom-file">
                                    
                                        <input type="file" name="casting_photo" class="custom-file-input" id="casting_photo">
                                         <span id="store_image"></span>
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                      <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_photo') }}</span>
                                     </div>
                                       <label class="custom-file-label" for="casting_photo">Choose file</label>

                                    </div>

                                 </div>

                                 <!--  <button type="submit" id="createBtn" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button> -->
                                
                                    <div class="form-group" align="center">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" />
            <input type="submit" name="action_button" id="action_button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Add" />
           </div>
              </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>

     
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#create_record').click(function(){
     $('.modal-title').text("Add New Record");
     $('#action_button').val("Add");
     $('#action').val("Add");
     $('#formModal').modal('show');
 });

$('#sample_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if($('#action').val() == 'Add')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"castingss",
    method:"POST",
    data: new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache:false,
    processData: false,
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     var html = '';
     if(data.errors)
     {
      html = '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
      for(var count = 0; count < data.errors.length; count++)
      {
       html += '<p>' + data.errors[count] + '</p>';
      }
      html += '</div>';
     }
     if(data.success)
     {
      html = '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.success + '</div>';
      $('#sample_form')[0].reset();
     /* $('#user_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();*/
     }
     $('#form_result').html(html);
    }
   })
  }

});

  });

</script>


</x-app-layout>
```

My Controller :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
       {
          
           $rules = array(
                'casting_name'    =>  'required',
                'casting_cin'     =>  'required',
                  'casting_email'    =>  'required|email',
                'casting_phone'     =>  'required|min:4',
                  'casting_age'    =>  'required',
                'casting_sexe'     =>  'required',
                  'casting_city'    =>  'required',
                'casting_address'     =>  'required',
                     'casting_photo'         =>  'required|image|max:2048'
            );
    
            $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    
            if($error->fails())
            {
                return response()->json(['errors' => $error->errors()->all()]);
            }
    
            $image = $request->file('casting_photo');
    
            $new_name = $request->get('hidden_id') . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
            $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
    
            $form_data = array(
               'casting_name' => $request->casting_name,
                 'casting_cin' => $request->casting_cin,
                 'casting_email' => $request->casting_email,
                 'casting_phone' => $request->casting_phone,
                  'casting_age' => $request->casting_age,
                 'casting_sexe' => $request->casting_sexe,
                 'casting_city' => $request->casting_city,
                 'casting_address' => $request->casting_address,  
                     'casting_photo'=>$new_name
            );
    
            Casting::create($form_data);
    
            return response()->json(['success' => 'Data Added successfully.']);
    
        }
```

For the moment everything is going well the data are inserted but the validation of the data is done after the click on the button submit.

My result for the moment :
[image]

As you see when I click on submit button I get the message of errors, while I did not want that I wanted at the time of the entry to get the message error.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

From what I read you are wanting to use a client-side validation, but in reality you are using a *server-side validation*, if you want to perform a *client-side validation*, that is, **a real-time validation** I recommend using **Jquery Validation**.
Here is a demo from the same official page: https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

And here the documentation of it: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Thank you for your reply but how can I use it with ajax ?